# Bi-directional communication with a Channel

Tags: go, channel

In the below code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

func getPage(url string) (int, error) {
    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }

    return len(body), nil
}

func getter(urlChan chan string, size chan int) {
    url := <-urlChan
    length, err := getPage(url)
    if err == nil {
        size <- length
        urlChan <- url
    }
}

func main() {
    urls := []string{"http://www.google.com/", "http://www.yahoo.com",
        "http://www.bing.com", "http://bbc.co.uk"}

    sizeChan := make(chan int)
    urlChan := make(chan string)

    for _, url := range urls {
        urlChan <- url
        go getter(urlChan, sizeChan)
    }

    for i := 0; i < len(urls); i++ {
        fmt.Printf("%s has length %d\n", <-urlChan, <-sizeChan)
    }
}
```

---

am using `urlChan` as bi-directional, to know the url(`urlChan`) for the given size(`sizeChan`) calculated.

For `getter()` go-routine, after making first string argument `url` to  `urlChan`, below output shows a hang situation:

```
$ go install github.com/shamhub/cs61a
$ 
$ 
$ bin/cs61a
```

---

1) How to perform bi-directional communication on a channel?

2) How to profile the status of go-routines for a given process?

Comment: Send SIGQUIT to the process to find out where the process is hung. Sending the `url` through a channel is unnecessarily complex. Simplify the code by passing the `url` as an argument, not as a value received through the channel: `func getter(url string, size chan int) { ... }`.

Comment: that is not correct, this will lead to unpredictable results as pushing to url and size channels might be interleaved across the multiple routines you are spawning. I cant find a case where you would use the same channel for both write then read. your return channel should be of a type that embeds all necessary information you want to send back (ie: `type xx struct { url string; len int; }`).

Comment: @CeriseLimón yes I already did that, but how do I correlate size to url in main goroutine?

Comment: Use `struct { url string; size int }` as channel element type.  If you need to know the index in `urls`, then pass the index to `getter` and use `struct { index int; size int }` as the channel element type.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Do I need to create channel with element type `struct { index int; size int }` in `main()` and pass on to `getter()`?

Comment: The type used to create a channel must be the same as the type when using the channel (except for the send-only and receive-only attributes).

Comment: @CeriseLimón One approach could be `size <- fmt.Sprintf("%s has length %d", url, length)` in `getter()` with channel as `string` type. These are minimum changes

Answer (score 3):

As others already noted, you can solve this problem a lot more simply:

```golang
type sized struct {
    url    string
    length int
    err    error
}

func sizer(url string, result chan<- sized, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    length, err := getPage(url)
    result <- sized{url, length, err}
}

func main() {
    urls := []string{"http://www.google.com/", "http://www.yahoo.com",
        "http://www.bing.com", "http://bbc.co.uk"}

    ch := make(chan sized)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for _, url := range urls {
        wg.Add(1)
        go sizer(url, ch, &wg)
    }
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(ch)
    }()

    for result := range ch {
        if result.err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("%s: %s\n", result.url, result.err)
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("%s: length = %d\n", result.url, result.length)
        }
    }
}
```

[Complete example on playground, though it can't dial out, so not really useful there.](https://play.golang.org/p/RERv3t0GHwy)

> How to perform bi-directional communication on a channel?

You can't.

Well, that's not entirely true.  Let's say instead: you *shouldn't*.

Suppose we have a channel:

```
var ch chan T
```

for some type T.

The *channel itself* is inherently ... well, I think *non-directional* is the right word:

- *anyone* can put any value of type T into the channel with `ch <- val`
- *anyone* can take any value of type T out of the channel with `var <- ch`

This clearly isn't unidirectional, but I think calling it *bidirectional* is misleading: it has a "put things in" side and a "take things out" side, both lumped into one channel instance, but the channel isn't associated with any particular *user*.  You can copy the channel value to a directional *instance* (see [What's the point of one-way channels in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13596186/1256452)), in either direction, but both are really just references to an underlying non-directional channel object.<sup>1</sup>  You can then pass the original channel, or a unidirectional-ized copy of it, to *any* user, or treat any of these as "global" (wide-scope) variables that anyone can use.

Now let's add two entities, which we'll call X and Y.  If channel `ch` is *buffered*, either or both of X and Y can put items in, and then either or both of A and B can take items out.  Items will come out in the order they went in, serializing access; if the channel is full, the attempt to put an item in will block; but items *do not* transfer specifically *from* X *to* Y.  In particular:

```
// Y: paused or stopped

// do this in X when ch is initially empty:
ch <- T{}
v := <-ch
```

Here, X puts a zero-valued `T` into the channel, then takes it back out.  This isn't directional.  X got *its own* data back.

If the channel *isn't* empty, but also isn't full, either X or Y can add something to it (as a queue), then take something off the front of the queue.  But that's just using the channel as a queue.  (See [Is it possible to use Go's buffered channel as a thread-safe queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10424144/1256452))

If this queue had certain features that it definitely lacks, you *could* use a single queue for a sort of bidirectional communication (see [Is two way comm possible using a single message queue in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22661079/1256452)).  But it doesn't have them.  If you really *need* bidirectional communication, the answer is obvious: use two queues.  Designate one queue—one channel—as the X-sends-to-Y channel, and the other as the Y-sends-to-X channel.

---

<sup>1</sup>The underlying channel is accessible / recoverable via `unsafe`, but don't do that unless you really know exactly what you're doing.  Someone who passed you a unidirectional instance probably doesn't intend for you to use the other "side" of the channel.

Comment: OK... So, if we do not use `wg` then `range ch` will block in `main()`

Comment: OK... your answer did not address the problem...what went wrong with `urlChan <- url` in `getsetter()`?

Comment: Does goroutine(`G`) block OS thread(`M`) on io block of `http.Get()`? or Does goroutine(`G`) gets removed from context(`P`) on io block by making OS thread(`M`) available for another go-routine?

Comment: I see no occurrences of `getsetter` on this page other than your own comments, so that's entirely unanswerable. As for your `urlChan <- url`: on the first trip through your loop, you are sending on an unbuffered channel with no function reading that channel. The queue's capacity is zero, so yes, the send blocks at that point.

Comment: No function reading that channel? `<-urlChan` is reading in `main()` go-routine

Comment: How `result chan<- sized` argument declaration of `getter()` different from `result chan sized`?

Comment: No, `main` is *not* reading that channel. `main` is in your first `for` loop. It has not yet reached your second `for` loop, and it never will because it blocks while attempting to send the URL on `urlChan`. As for the declaration `result chan<- sized`, that merely limits this copy of the channel value to send-only (write-to-queue) operations. See the links I included in my answer. Read *all* of the answer, not just parts of it.

Answer (score 1):

you got to read and practice the go tour, i believe every details used in below code will be explained there, but, here is one solution

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "sync"
)

func getPage(url string) (int, error) {
    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }

    return len(body), nil
}

type result struct {
    url string
    len int
    err error
}

func main() {
    urls := []string{"http://www.google.com/", "http://www.yahoo.com",
        "http://www.bing.com", "http://bbc.co.uk"}

    resChan := make(chan result)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for _, url := range urls {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(url string) {
            defer wg.Done()
            l, err := getPage(url)
            resChan <- result{url: url, len: l, err: err}
        }(url)
    }

    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(resChan)
    }()

    for r := range resChan {
        if r.err != nil {
            log.Printf("failed to fetch %q: %v\n", r.url, r.err)
            continue
        }
        fmt.Printf("%s has length %d\n", r.url, r.len)
    }
}
```

It is not ideal because it will not limit the number of concurrent outgoing requests.

About, `2) How to profile the status of go-routines for a given process?`

See pprof tooling. There is a doc https://golang.org/doc/diagnostics.html

and https://stackoverflow.com/a/19145992/4466350